# Checkbox to choose which columns to include in graph

Tags: tableau-api

Is there any way I can have a checkbox to decide which columns to include in a graph. For example, this would be the basic graph.

[image]

And if I check the Make Column, the graph change as shown below:

[image]

Is there any way to implement this?

Edit 1: A little clarification, when all makes are selected, I want to show the basic graph with sum of record counts for all makes.